# how to pass database variable in URL anchor tag

Tags: php, database, laravel

```
            $permissions = DB::table('file_permissions')
                           ->leftjoin('adminfiles','file_permissions.fileid','adminfiles.id')
                           ->where('user_id', $user)
                           ->get();
```

I am getting these file permissions as per user from the database and listing them in the left column of the admin panel

```
<ul class="treeview-menu">
            @foreach($permissions as $permission)

            <li><a href="{{ url('$permission->fileaddress')  }}"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> {{ $permission->filename }}</a></li>

            @endforeach
          </ul>
```

But in the output it makes url like this

```
http://localhost/laravel/$permission-%3Efileaddress
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Why did you put `$permission->fileaddress` in quotes? What does happen if you remove them?

Comment: try to use `.` `url('.$permission->fileaddress.')`

Comment: Try this: `href='{{ url("$permission->fileaddress")  }}'` hope it's works for you!!!

Comment: thanks @RimonKhan it works

Answer (score 0):

Check the Laravel route parameters

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-parameters

Example (see docs)

```
Route::get('user/{id}', function ($id) {
  return 'User '.$id;
});
```

Link like that

```
<a href="{{ route('route-name', ['id' => $id]) }}">link</a>
```

Comment: actually route name is coming from database and i need to call that name in the url anchor not ID

Comment: Maybe that helps you -  url('path') . '?' . http_build_query(['param1' => 'value', 'param2' => 'value']);

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the trick.

`<a href="{{ url('') }}/{{ $permission->fileaddress }}">`